# Ranking order within groupby groups

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, rank

Say I have the following dataframe `df_grouped`:

```py
                     Sale
custid | product   |
-------+-----------+------
1      |   iPhone  | 3000
       |   android | 2000  
2      |   iPhone  | 1500
       |   android | 2500
```

and I want a ranking within each group (`customerid`) ending with

```py
                     Sale
custid | product   |
-------+-----------+------
1      |   iPhone  | 1
       |   android | 2
2      |   iPhone  | 2
       |   android | 1
```

If I just do `df_grouped.rank()` I get a global ranking

```py
                     Sale
custid | product   |
-------+-----------+------
1      |   iPhone  | 1
       |   android | 3
2      |   iPhone  | 4
       |   android | 2
```

but I want the ranking within each group. I can loop over each `custid` and apply `rank` to each of those groups, but isn't there a faster/cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html):

```
df['Rank'] = df.groupby(level='custid')['Sale'].rank()
```

Comment: A short comment; what messed it up was that my dataframe was already an aggreagated groupby i.e, `df_grouped=df.groupby(["custid","product"])["sale"].sum()`. Thus I had to groupby again e.g `rank=df_grouped.groupby("custid")["sale"].rank()`